Querying in DynamoDB (with dynamodb-geo npm) - Error Message: ValidationException: Query key condition not supported
So I'm having trouble implementing dynamodb-geo into my program that finds the foodtrucks within 1 km of a specified location. I was following this video as a tutorial for doing so. I'll attach my code below and my error message, along with any helpful information:
'use strict'

const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({
accessKeyId: 'my access id', // dw i have an actual id
secretAccessKey: 'my secret key', // dw i have an actual key
region: 'my region' //this matches with the region the table is in
});
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB()
const ddbGeo = require('dynamodb-geo')

const config = new ddbGeo.GeoDataManagerConfiguration(ddb, 'powerhouse_table')
config.hashKeyLength = 5

const myGeoTableManager = new ddbGeo.GeoDataManager(config)

myGeoTableManager.queryRadius({
RadiusInMeter: 1000,
CenterPoint: {
latitude: 30,
longitude: -90
}
})
.then((locations) => {
console.log('Locations found: ', locations.length)
console.log(locations)
})

And my error message:
  resp.error = util.error(new Error(), error);
                          ^

ValidationException: Query key condition not supported

Originally, it gave me an error for not having an index called geohash-index, and so I made a GSI for geohash-index. The partition key was 'geohash' with a data type of Number (I tried both Number and String as my data type but I got the same error message). I didn't set the optional sortKey.
Additionally, here is a snippet of my table:
vendor-id is the table's partition key
Does anyone know how to fix the error? Thanks.
By the way, I tried changing the Data Types on the Global Secondary Index, but both string and number gives me the same error unfortunately (I asked ChatGPT on why number should be the GSI data type for the partition key and it said that AWS stores the geohashes numerically).

The problem
The error you’re getting is a result of how your table i.e. "powerhouse_table" is currently structured.
By default, dynamo-geo expects the partition key of your table to be called/named hashKey. Also, the value of this key is auto-generated and managed by dynamo-geo. See more details here.
In your current table structure, the name of the partition key is vendor_id and the value is not what dynamo-geo expects.
When you execute a radius query, dynamo-geo will use hashKey as the partition key of the query generated and sent to Dynamo, and of course, this would fail, you don’t have such key on the table.
The solution
You should adjust your table structure to fit the requirements of dynamo-geo.
I think the easiest way to create a table that will work well with dynamo-geo is using the GeoTableUtil.getCreateTableRequest utility function. It will generate a createTable request with the attributes and index definitions necessary to work with dynamo-geo. You can execute the create table request against your dynamo db instance.
You should take a look at the example here, it should clarify a lot of things too.
I understand you’re currently partitioning the "powerhouse_table" by vendor_id because you want to be able to query by vendorId, to achieve this after the table restructuring, you can create a Global Secondary Index with vendor_id as the partition key.
